# This user's credential isn't valid for this project, Error on confirmResult.confirm(codeInput) in react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key.

Everything working fine without any changes today I get above error, When I send request for verification code get success from **signInWithPhoneNumber** but verification code didn't getting.

I tried with adding test number in firebase console but get same error.

Let me know if any know how to fixed that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried some solution but no hope, so I decide reset my phone (factory reset) and tada, its work

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the cash of google play services to solve it.

This happens when I uninstall and reinstall the app multiple times and signing in into multiple accounts and change the system clock frequently for testing.

Comment: Where to find Google Play Services?